# Passing empty list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, tail

I'm going through some exercises in Graham Hutton's Programming in Haskell. In chapter 4 I have to create a function that returns the tail of a list, or, if given an empty list, simply return an empty list.

I've written the following:

```
putStrLn "Exercise 4a"
let safeTail1 :: [a] -> [a]
    safeTail1 x = if (null x) then [] else (tail x)
print (safeTail1 [1..5])      -- This works, returns the tail [2,3,4,5]
print (safeTail1 (tail [1]))  -- This works, returns [] since tail of one-item list is []
print (safeTail1 [])          -- Error!
```

The first test correctly returns the tail.
The second test creates an empty list and passes it to `safeTail1` and correctly returns an empty list.
In the third test I attempt to pass an empty list, but I get the following error message:

```
chapter04.hs:97:5: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `print'
      prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 13 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (safeTail1 [])
      In the expression:
        do putStrLn "Chapter 04 - Start!"
           putStrLn "Absolute"
           let absolute :: Int -> Int
               absolute n = ...
           print (absolute (- 5))
           ....
      In an equation for `main':
          main
            = do putStrLn "Chapter 04 - Start!"
                 putStrLn "Absolute"
                 let absolute :: Int -> Int
                     ....
                 ....
   |
97 |     print (safeTail1 [])
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Why can't I pass an empty list?

Comment: It is unclear what the type of the item is in `safeTail1 []`, you can pass a type hint: `safeTail1 ([] :: [Int])` for example.

Comment: While the linked *question* looks rather different, its accepted *answer* is exactly what you need to understand.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thanks, that makes sense! Write it in an answer and you can have a tick!